# Using a stored procedure containing dynamic SQL to create a report in C# (Report viewer)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, reportviewer

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that I want to use to create a report in my application (c#).

Because the table in the procedure is dynamically created I am having trouble using it to create a report.

How can I use this procedure to create a report in my application?

I am using VS2010, SQL Server 2008 R2

I created a dataset in VS but not sure how to use it from there. The report wizard cannot use the dataset I created.

I gave thought to somehow using this to create a view and then generate a dataset from that but could not figure that out.

I hope I have provided enough info for someone to give me some direction.

```
PROCEDURE sp_RD_Reporting_View_ExportedData_For_Period    
(   
@StartDate date,   
@EndDate date   
)  
AS  
CREATE TABLE #tmp  
(  
    StartDate DATETIME,  
    EndDate DATETIME,  
    FomatedDate VARCHAR(20)  
)  
--Calculate the date ranges   
;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (  
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
        SELECT 1+n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 6 )  
INSERT INTO #tmp  
SELECT  
    DATEADD(DAY,-n,@StartDate),  
    DATEADD(DAY,-n,@EndDate),  
    convert(varchar, DATEADD(DAY,-n,@EndDate), 110)  
FROM  
    Nbrs  
ORDER BY  
    -n  
--The date columns for the pivot  
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(FomatedDate),  
                     QUOTENAME(FomatedDate))    
FROM   
    #tmp  
--Declaring some dynamic sql and executing it  
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=  
N'SELECT  
    *  
FROM  
(  
    SELECT   ExportData.EmployeeID AS EmpID,  
            ABRAempInfo.EmpFullName AS Name,  
            ExportData.PayType AS PayType,   
            tmp.FomatedDate,   
            SUM(ExportData.Quantity) AS Hours   
    FROM ExportData   
    JOIN ABRAempInfo    
    ON ExportData.EmployeeID = ABRAempInfo.EmpID  
    JOIN #tmp AS tmp  
    ON ExportData.ChargeDate = tmp.FomatedDate  
    WHERE ChargeDate BETWEEN tmp.StartDate AND tmp.EndDate  
    GROUP BY ExportData.EmployeeID, ExportData.PayType, tmp.FomatedDate,   ABRAempInfo.EmpFullName  

) AS p  
PIVOT  
(  
    SUM(Hours)  
    FOR FomatedDate IN ('+@cols+')  
) AS pvt'  

EXECUTE(@query)  
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into something that I think is similar - trying to get Linq to Sql to build me a result set from a stored proc that uses Dynamic SQL to select results. Here is how I solved my issue... it is very much a work around, but you won't really be able to get a wizard to work off a dynamic result set. Also note, that if your dynamic sql returns differing columns, it is not likely to work.

1. Run your dynamic statement and output only the SQL statement (print the statement, don't execute it)
2. Modify your stored procedure to return output via the sql statement you got from #1
3. You now have a standard stored procedure - use this to build your report from.
4. After your report is tested and working ok, Modify your stored procedure again and plug the dynamic sql back in.

Comment: I get where you’re going with this. Just not sure what you mean by modify my SP by the output of step 1. Can you give me an example of how you would code this?

Comment: I gave it a try and here is what the PRINT but when I run just what it returned it errors saying invalid object name #tmp. I commented out the DROP TABLE #tmp beofre running.

Comment: On second thought... I fear I may be steering you wrong... I'm not sure if your reporting will work when you will get different column headers (due to the pivot) when you run it. Are you using SSRS? If so, you should be able use a matrix to write your report.

Comment: Without seeing your sql, it is hard to say what is going wrong. The bottom line is that reporting wizards/tools are likely to not like Dynamic SQL as they won't be able to build a column list. If you "fake" your dynamic SQL and build your stored proc with the fake sql you should be able to use a wizard to generate a report. You can then replace your fake sql with your dynamic sql and the reporting tool should be none the wiser that the stored proc has changed.

Comment: No not using SSRS. Seems there should be a way to load the resaults if this script into a dataset and create the table in the fly, just cant figure it out, and yes it is the PIVOT and changing columns that will make what you suggest difficult. Thats for the help though. I am going to see if we have SSRS installed.

Comment: Normally you do the pivot in your presentation layer (i.e. your C# app or SSRS), not in the database layer.