# ASP.NET & Crystal Report: load datasource from a stored procedure with temp tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I have used a stored procedure to achieve my desired output in displaying the monhtly sales report of tenants on one mall / location. The stored procedure contains multiple temp tables (due to the limitation of the existing database structure / schema) to accomplish what I need to accomplish. The procedure was indeed successful in gridview.

**Here's the stored procedure**

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName]
// parameters

@Location int, // the location number
@CurrentMonthStart date ,
@MonthCurrent varchar(20),
@MonthPrevious varchar(20)



AS
BEGIN
 //Using the CurrentMonthStart data, I formulated the other essential variable needed for the query to run
declare @PreviousMonthStart date
declare @PreviousMonthEnd date
declare @CurrentMonthEnd date
declare @query varchar (8000)

set @PreviousMonthStart  =   convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(m,-1, @CurrentMonthStart) , 101)
set @PreviousMonthEnd   =   convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(d,-1, @CurrentMonthStart) , 101)
set @CurrentMonthEnd    =   convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m,1, @CurrentMonthStart)) , 101)



// i used temp table several times
select b.tenantcode, b.date , SUM(a.other)as discount
        INTO #NewDiscountTable
        from DAILY a INNER JOIN DISCOUNT b on a.date = b.date and a.tenantcode = b.tenantcode 
        WHERE b.date between @PreviousMonthStart  AND @CurrentMonthEnd  and A.location = @Location 
        group by b.date, b.tenantcode 
        order by b.tenantcode 


        select tenantcode , SUM(discount) as Approved_Disc
        into #NewDiscountTableFinal
        from #NewDiscountTable 
        where  date between @PreviousMonthStart  AND @PreviousMonthEnd
        group by tenantcode

        select tenantcode , SUM(discount) as Approved_Disc2
        into #NewDiscountTableFinal2
        from #NewDiscountTable 
        where  date between @CurrentMonthStart AND @CurrentMonthEnd  
        group by tenantcode




select  b.sqm  as 'FLOOR AREA/SQM',  b.name as 'RETAIL PARTNERS' , 
        convert(varchar(10), a.date, 101) as Date, datename(weekday, a.date) as Day,
        ((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)+ SUM(a.other)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as GSC,
        a.location , a.tenantcode 
        into #NewDailySalesTenderTable
        from  TENANT b inner join LOCATION c on b.location=c.location inner join DAILY a on a.tenantcode=b.tenantcode

        where a.location = @Location and b.status  > 1 and
            a.date  BETWEEN  @PreviousMonthStart and @CurrentMonthEnd 

        GROUP BY  b.name, a.date , a.location , a.tenantcode , b.sqm
        order by b.name, A.DATE



        select  [FLOOR AREA/SQM], [RETAIL PARTNERS] , Tenantcode,  SUM(GSC) as GSCwithOtherDisc
        into #NewDailySalesTenderTableFinal 
        from #NewDailySalesTenderTable 
        where date  BETWEEN  @PreviousMonthStart and @PreviousMonthEnd
        GROUP BY [Retail Partners], tenantcode, [FLOOR AREA/SQM]
        ORDER BY [Retail Partners]



        select  [FLOOR AREA/SQM], [RETAIL PARTNERS] ,  Tenantcode,  SUM(GSC) as GSCwithOtherDisc2
        into #NewDailySalesTenderTableFinal2 
        from #NewDailySalesTenderTable 
        where  date between @CurrentMonthStart  AND @CurrentMonthEnd  
        GROUP BY [Retail Partners], tenantcode, [FLOOR AREA/SQM]
        ORDER BY [Retail Partners]



select A.[FLOOR AREA/SQM] , a.[Retail Partners], 

          case when a.tenantcode  in (select d.tenantcode from #NewDiscountTableFinal2 d ) -- case within case kasi pag 0 yung divisor may error
            then Round(((c.GSCwithOtherDisc2   - d.Approved_Disc2  )/(case when a.[FLOOR AREA/SQM] = 0 then null else (a.[FLOOR AREA/SQM]) end)   ),0)
            else Round(((c.GSCwithOtherDisc2  - 0)/ (case when a.[FLOOR AREA/SQM] = 0 then null else (a.[FLOOR AREA/SQM]) end) ),0)
            end as 'SALES/SQM',



            case when a.tenantcode  in (select d.tenantcode from #NewDiscountTableFinal2 d )
            then Round((c.GSCwithOtherDisc2   - d.Approved_Disc2  ),0)
            else Round((c.GSCwithOtherDisc2  - 0),0)
            end as CurrentMonth,

            case when a.tenantcode  in (select b.tenantcode from #NewDiscountTableFinal b )
            then Round((a.GSCwithOtherDisc  - b.Approved_Disc ),0)
            else Round((a.GSCwithOtherDisc  - 0),0)
            end as PreviousMonth


            --case when a.tenantcode  in (select b.tenantcode from #NewDiscountTableFinal b )
            --then Round((((((c.GSCwithOtherDisc2   - d.Approved_Disc2  )- (a.GSCwithOtherDisc  - b.Approved_Disc )) / (a.GSCwithOtherDisc  - b.Approved_Disc )) * 100)),0)
            --else Round((C.GSCwithOtherDisc2  - 0),0)
            --end as '%INC/DEC'

        into #FinalResult
        FROM #NewDailySalesTenderTableFinal  a left join  #NewDiscountTableFinal b on a.tenantcode = b.tenantcode join
        #NewDailySalesTenderTableFinal2 c on a.tenantcode = c.tenantcode left join #NewDiscountTableFinal2 d on c.tenantcode = d.tenantcode


 set @query = 'select [Retail Partners],[FLOOR AREA/SQM], ' +
'replace(convert(varchar,cast(([SALES/SQM])  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ''SALES/SQM'',' +
'replace(convert(varchar,cast((CurrentMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthCurrent  +
',replace(convert(varchar,cast((PreviousMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthPrevious   +

',case when PreviousMonth = 0 
then ''N/A''' +
'else  replace(convert(varchar,cast(Round((((CurrentMonth-PreviousMonth)/ PreviousMonth    ) *100),0) as money),1), ''.00'','''') 
end as ''%INC/DEC'' ' +
'from #FinalResult '
 execute(@query)


END
```

**I HAVE FOUND OUT WHERE THE PROBLEM IS COMING FROM**
This last part from the stored procedure is the source of the conflict. The part where I made the PARAMETERS - @MonthCurrent and @MonthPrevious the generated column of the query, those columns are based on what the user has selected. I isolated the problem by commenting out those part to see if it will run in Crystal Report and it did.

**QUESTION IS: How can join those columns in Crystal REPORT?**

```
set @query = 'select [Retail Partners],[FLOOR AREA/SQM], ' +
    'replace(convert(varchar,cast(([SALES/SQM])  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ''SALES/SQM'',' +
    'replace(convert(varchar,cast((CurrentMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthCurrent  +
    ',replace(convert(varchar,cast((PreviousMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthPrevious   +

    ',case when PreviousMonth = 0 
    then ''N/A''' +
    'else  replace(convert(varchar,cast(Round((((CurrentMonth-PreviousMonth)/ PreviousMonth    ) *100),0) as money),1), ''.00'','''') 
    end as ''%INC/DEC'' ' +
    'from #FinalResult '
```

**Sample screenshot, successfully run the SP in gridview**

[image]

**Now, I would like to incorporate also the same stored procedure, this time filling data in Crystal Report, using the said SP as my datasource. Here's what have I started**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

//I pass the values of parameter from the page to the print page using Session
        Label1.Text = Session["Location"].ToString();
        int Loc = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);

        Label2.Text = Session["CurrentMonthStart"].ToString();
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Label2.Text);

        Label3.Text = Session["MonthCurrent"].ToString();
        Label4.Text = Session["MonthPrevious"].ToString();


      report.Load(Server.MapPath("MonthlySalesReport.rpt"));

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

        report.SetParameterValue(0, Loc);
        report.SetParameterValue(1, dt);
        report.SetParameterValue(2, Label3.Text);
        report.SetParameterValue(3, Label4.Text);

        con.Close();

    }
```

This is the error the is caused by the stated problem in the stored pro

*One or more fields could not be found in the result set. Use Verify Database to update the report. Error in File MonthlySalesReport {0E90B4CE-8D1A-4712-BE05-9C1DC8CC9ADB}.rpt: The rowset column could not be found.*

Comment: did you try to run each of the query's one by one.. it appears taht you are trying to bind a column filed name that does not exist in your query.. make sure the spelling is correct on the report as well as in the query have you stepped thru the code as well..?

Comment: hi @DJKRAZE Yes, I run each query one by one IN THE BACK-END PART - SQL, and it actually run successfully, that's why I was able to load a perfect data in the gridview.

Comment: dt is actually the @CurrentMonthStart parameter from Label2.text, I need to convert it to datetime datatype because in the stored pro, it is tagged as datetime.

Comment: if you are using SET NOCOUNT ON; in your sp, then try to remove this row count. Then rebuild solution and try to re-run the report.

Comment: so what column is it saying can not be found ..? did you look at the CrystalReport designer to make sure when it tries to bind that it's binding to the actual column name

Comment: if you look at my SP the last line query, the column in it does tally with my column in the CR, only thing that's is uncertain with me is the TWO MONTHS generated (MonthCurrent and MOnthPrevious parameter) which is not static.. however in CR when i am asked to enter values, I am entering a static default month name, DOES IT MATTER?

Comment: I have updated my question after finding the CAUSE OF THE ERROR. Please see for your guidance. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR is only able to read what is returned by your query.  You can see similar issues [Here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting/Crystal_Reports/Q_26658992.html) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464503/using-a-stored-procedure-containing-dynamic-sql-to-create-a-report-in-c-sharp-r?rq=1). All these people have similar issue like you ricky. Read and see if it can help. If it doesn't, don't waste your time find a work around. If i were you. I had create a  new table `dbo.MyTempTable` and refresh it when ever the procedure is called like.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTempTable
INSERT INTO dbo.myTempTable(Col1, Col 2, Col3, Col4 , Col5, Col6 ..)

    select [Retail Partners],[FLOOR AREA/SQM], ' +
    'replace(convert(varchar,cast(([SALES/SQM])  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ''SALES/SQM'',' +
    'replace(convert(varchar,cast((CurrentMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthCurrent  +
    ',replace(convert(varchar,cast((PreviousMonth)  as money),1), ''.00'','''') as ' + @MonthPrevious   +

    ',case when PreviousMonth = 0 
    then ''N/A''' +
    'else  replace(convert(varchar,cast(Round((((CurrentMonth-PreviousMonth)/ PreviousMonth    ) *100),0) as money),1), ''.00'','''') 
    end as ''%INC/DEC'' ' +
    'from #FinalResult '
```

In the above you always empty the temptable. Then populate the temp table with what ever you return from your query.

Then proceed and create another procedure or simply view. like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTempTableProcedure

AS 
  BEGIN 
     SELECT * FROM myTempTable
  END
```

Go to your report and  update the datasource to MyTempTableProcedure. This is walk around. In your backend c#. Execute the procedure first before printing the result. You will not have problem with this because you already did with gridview.

```
        Label1.Text = Session["Location"].ToString();
        int Loc = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);

        Label2.Text = Session["CurrentMonthStart"].ToString();
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Label2.Text);

        Label3.Text = Session["MonthCurrent"].ToString();
        Label4.Text = Session["MonthPrevious"].ToString();

       //EXECCUTE the procedure here
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spName",con)
        {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType .StoredProcedure;
           cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Location", LOC);
           cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@CurrentMonthStart ",   Label3.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@date ",   dt);
           cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@CurrentMonthStart ",   Label4.Text);

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("MonthlySalesReport.rpt"));

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;

        con.Close();
```

This should be a walk around. This is what i am thinking though. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now, one question will that be able to retain the dynamic column name for MONTH CURRENT AND MONTH PREVIOUS? since it has created a new column from the temp table?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer. You create your new table with the exact column names you like . Then insert the records return by your selection in to the table. Trust me this is straight forward walk around. IF your query returns columns, Create your new table with the columns names return form temporary tables . Then insert everything into the new table. Then your new Storeprocedure select * from your new table and send to ur report. Thats easy isn't it?

Comment: yeah, it sounds cool, It is actually very alike somehow with what have I done in the whole store procedure of mine, where I used temp table to achieve the final output i desired in the gridview What I really want is for that to also be achieved in Crystal Report. In the inspiration of your idea or concept, I have also thought of just creating a copy of my stored procedure for Crystal report and just change the column name with static name, not the one paramerized.

Comment: Hi this method worked! thanks, I have also thought of other ways to achieve what I want based on your idea using the codes that I have started based on your idea.